# How can I prevent A user from pick gif image in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to prevent the user from pick a gif image from the photo library how I can do that? I don't want the gif images to be shown

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting [UIImagePickerController.mediaTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619173-mediatypes) explicitly for the types you want.

By default it is set to `[kUTTypeImage]` which covers all image types - jpeg, png, gif, heif and more...

You can try setting this like -

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

let targetTypes: [String] = [
    kUTTypeAppleICNS as String,
    kUTTypeBMP as String,
    // kUTTypeGIF as String, // We don't want this
    kUTTypeICO as String,
    // kUTTypeImage as String, // We don't want this
    kUTTypeJPEG as String,
    kUTTypeJPEG2000 as String,
    kUTTypeLivePhoto as String,
    kUTTypePNG as String,
    kUTTypeRawImage as String,
    kUTTypeTIFF as String,
    // and anything else you would like to try
]

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

// Method 1 : Check with system first and then set
let allowedTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .savedPhotosAlbum) // .photosLibrary
if let allowedTypes = allowedTypes, 
   allowedTypes.contains(kUTTypeImage as String) {
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = targetTypes.filter { 
        UTTypeConformsTo($0 as CFString, kUTTypeImage)
    }
}

// Method 2 : May crash, needs testing
imagePicker.mediaTypes = targetTypes
```