# Selecting only PNG and JPEG in Image picker

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to limit the user to only pick a PNG or JPEG image from the photo library.

I'm using SwiftUI in my project, this is my `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

```
struct ImagePickerRaw: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerRaw>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UTType.png.identifier, UTType.jpeg.identifier]
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerRaw>) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: ImagePickerRaw?
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePickerRaw) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage,
               let parent = parent {
                parent.selectedImage = image
            }
            
            parent?.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            parent = nil
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to limit the user's choice, but I get an error message saying:

`ImagePickerDemo[411:12746] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 0`

I have also looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68055420/14591716) but my app just crashes.

I have tried `imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UTType.image.identifier]` but that includes gifs.

Is there a way I can limit the user to pick images only (excluding gifs)?

Comment: I assume the available media types depends on what the `sourceType` is, there is a `availableMediaTypes(for:)` function for UIImagePickerController so maybe play around with that method to see what media type can be used for a given source type.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have tried that and the available media types are `["public.image", "public.movie"]`. Which does not help much, I needed something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Works as documented:

[image: demo]

Check for available types per call (as below) and choose which are to be used

```
[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
    self.sourceType];
```

Probably you wanted `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

Comment: I wanted a way to pic only images from the photo library, specifically JPEG and PNGs. I have tried `availableMediaTypes(for:)` it prints out `["public.image", "public.movie"]` I wanted something more specific.